# How to get a specific info on an Html page, using Cheerio on GAS?

Tags: html, google-apps-script, web-scraping, google-sheets, cheerio

I haven't been able to identify any class, id, etc where the code is supposed to get the information from.
Here's the html page and the piece of information I should get everyday:
[image]

...and here's the piece of code I'm trying to use:

```
    var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://ovoonline.com.br/", options).getContentText();
    const $ = Cheerio.load(content);
    Logger.log($('td[colspan="2"]').text());
```

This is its selector, but it doesn't output the correct result:

```
body > table > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) > table:nth-child(2) > tbody > tr:nth-child(6) > td > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(18) > td > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
    var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://ovoonline.com.br/",options)
                  .getContentText();

   const $ = Cheerio.load(content);
   Logger.log($('td[width="45"]').eq(1).text());
```

Result Log:

[image]

Comment: HI! Thanks a lot. This does get a price, but the one I'm after, I need to login first and then get the price from the table which is inside many other tables. Above, there's an update.

Comment: When I prepared the query I did it with the home page because I could not log in, can you send the complete html code?

Comment: Here it is...https://docs.google.com/document/d/1kDbrgJ8SeCsSJ5JxJMZHctXn-_a_O4IMC4JocPZ_5DY/edit?usp=sharing
I understand the effort/time here...I really do! Muchas gracias!

Comment: I have modified the answer, maybe it will help you.